# indexPathsForVisibleRows returns the total table size instead of visible after resize

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I am building a chat app, its going all good until i started implementing the auto scroll for `UITableView` when the keyboard shows up/down.

The `indexPathsForVisibleRows`'s resulting `NSArray` size was increasing after scrolls even if the height of every row/cell is constant. I searched on here and found out that there was a bug. According to the suggestions, i added the below line:

```
[table visibleCells];
```

before using `indexPathsForVisibleRows`:

```
scrollPosition = (NSIndexPath*)[[table indexPathsForVisibleRows] objectAtIndex:0];
```

in:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

This fixed the issue when the keyboard was hidden and the table was fullsized (not resized).

When the user taps on the textField, the keyboard shows up and the `UITableView`'s height gets decreased by the amount of the keyboard's height.

At this point when a scroll happens, the get around of using

```
[table visibleCells];
```

does not work and the resulting size of the `indexPathsForVisibleRows` `NSArray` becomes the total rows of the table instead of just the visible ones.

Is this another Bug or am i doing something wrong?